# FXML form load error when initialize variable is overriden

Tags: javafx, tableview, populate

I'm working on an fxml project. I want to populate a tableview from a database.

```
@FXML private TableView<complaints>tableview;
@FXML private TableColumn<complaints, Integer>ComplaintNo;
@FXML private TableColumn<complaints, String>Complaint;
@FXML private TableColumn<complaints, String>HandleComplaint;
```

this is the initializing of the attributes.

```
@Override
public void initialize(URL url,ResourceBundle resources
{
ComplaintNo.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<complaints, Integer>("ComplaintNo"));
   Complaint.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<complaints, String>("Complaint"));
   HandleComplaint.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<complaints, String>("HandleComplaint"));
   tableview.setItems(data);
}
```

that is the override of method initialize.

I tried to get a resultset where it gave me an error, therefore I tried to load the table from a hardcoded list.
Below is the observablelist method:

```
private int count=1;
ObservableList<complaints> data=FXCollections.observableArrayList(
new complaints(count++, "asd", "sadasd"),
new complaints(count++, "asd", "sadasd"),
new complaints(count++, "asd", "sadasd"),
new complaints(count++, "asd", "sadasd")

);
```

When I load the fxml to a stage a list of errors are given. When I comment the initialize method body and try to load the fxml the application runs. But the table doesn't populate. Can anyone point me out where I've gone wrong here?

This is the fxml part of the relevant table view

```
<TableView layoutX="269.0" layoutY="86.0" prefHeight="319.0" prefWidth="527.0"> 
    <columns> 
        <TableColumn fx:id="ComplaintNo" prefWidth="190.0" text="ComplaintNo" />
        <TableColumn fx:id="Complaint" prefWidth="162.0" text="Complaint" />
        <TableColumn fx:id="HandleComplaint" prefWidth="174.0" text="HandleComplaint" />
    </columns>
</TableView>
```

Comment: Please post the error message, and identify which lines in the code it refers to. You will likely have to post some of your FXML too. Ideally, you should create a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: error is given in the output as exception in application start method.

Answer (score 0):

You have not set an `fx:id` for the `TableView`, consequently the `tableview` field in the controller will not be initialized.

So my guess (since you haven't posted the exception) is that you are getting a `NullPointerException` when you call

```
tableview.setItems(data);
```